# How do Residual layers not inhibit the learning?

Tags: residual-networks

My understanding of residual layers is that we can take a layer and branch it into two paths. One going the typical path for a network, and the other is an identity mapping forward over the calculating layers. This solves the vanishing gradient problem when we have a lot of layers since regardless of what happens we'll always have the original inputs.

But how doesn't this affect the learning process? If we have `h(x) = Conv(x) -> BN(x) -> ReLU(x)`, normally this would result in `f(x) = h(x)`. But in a residual layer we have `f(x) = h(x) + x`. How do we stop that additional `x` from affecting any of the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it to affect the results. The simple answer is that it's like building a statistical model: you use linear combination+ nonlinear terms.  Note also that a linear deep network has non convex optimization surface see https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6120

Comment: I was under the impression that you can plug these residual blocks into an already trained network and it'll still work. Is that correct or do the weights have to be re-learned?

Comment: I don't know where you got that idea. People have trained 100 layer residual networks which would be impossible without.